# I am getting an error on if recordset = nothing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a function that opens a recordset. At the end of the function I want to close the recordset if it wasn't closed already, for error catching purposes.

When I try running the function I get the following compile error: **Invalid use of object.** Since I'm not trying to change the value of the recordset object, there should be no reason for this error to appear.

```
Dim rs as Recordset
...

If Not rs = Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: You can massively simplify your code by using the `DMax` function.

Comment: @Andre, Thanks! You have no idea how much you helped me. But originally, my code gets the maximum value of a **date** field. Does it work on that type as well?

Comment: Yes, DMax works on date/time fields too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement should be :

```
If Not rs is Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Since Nothing is an object that means **unknown**, it doesn't **equal** anything. Not even itself.

Answer (score 2):

Change this piece of code:

```
If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Also if it's clean-up procedure closing code, just use `On Error Resume Next` before invalidating open objects, no need to check if they are valid or not.

Answer (score -1):

It looks as it you are trying to close the recordset when it is already closed.

Perhaps this might work:

```
If rs <> Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    rs = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Compile error too, it must be `If Not rs Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Your right that I made a  mistake in the If statement. Originally it was `if Not` in my code. I foergot to put it in the question, and I changed it now. But `if rs Nothing` gets the same error.

Comment: `rs = nothing` is wrong as well.  Since rs is an **object**, you should use `set` to change it's value. 'Set rs = Nothing`.